# What would be the best approach of adding 100,000+ records to a MySQL database via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing an application and have over 100,000 records, that have been read in from a file, which need to be inserted into a MySQL database.

What would be the best approach of inserting these to the database?

The approach I'm currently working from is generating a SQL query to insert all the records in one call to the database.

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2)
VALUES
(123, 456),
(125, 984),
...
```

Is there a limit to the number of records that can be inserted at once?  And in terms of performance is this the best method?

I have considered an alternative of splitting the records into a number of queries but I'm unsure if this would have any benefit?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you are going with a better approach mysqldump does the same insertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're doing it is indeed very efficient. The maximum query length is determined by the max_allowed_packet setting so you may need to split the query into several queries, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: Regardless of any configured limits, you might want to limit the throughput anyway to give the server 'some time to breath'. If this is a live server that runs other processes, it is not bad practice to do the inserts in sensible chunks, take a short pause (couple of ms) and continue. This to prevent bad performance for those other processes and prevent possible table locks (which again is only an issue if you do a whole bunch of other things on the same database server). If you want to increase performance and fix locking issues, you should look in to the tx_isolation layer parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding one row at a time with `LOW_PRIORITY` or `DELAYED` depending on your engine. The reason for this is that other users of your table will still have access to read and write once in a while instead of having the entire table locked for an extended period of time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that will definitely come in useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions and/or format not withstanding, using

[load data infile to import the file directly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: The actual content of the file that I'm reading from requires a lot of processing to get the information I'm after, otherwise this would have worked great!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) is probably the best way to go. Especially if the data file you're reading from is already in a format that can be used by it.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider as well the LOAD DATA INFILE command of MySQL to insert data from a CSV file.